# Как распечатать PDF файл?

Tags: c#, pdf, печать

Пытаюсь через консольное приложение распечатать файл, но к сожаленью печатает пустой файл. Печатать через  `Process` не интересует, так как я сам хочу выбирать принтер с которого мне печатать.

```
PrintDialog printdg = new PrintDialog();
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrinterSettings = printdg.PrinterSettings;
pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Adobe PDF";
pd.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = @"D:\1.pdf";
pd.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();

pd.Print();
pd.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Есть бесплатный [PdfSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PdfSharp/), более детально описано [здесь](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/10/05/pdf-generation-and-printing-in-net-2.html).

```
// Define or otherwise determine the path of the Adobe reader
PdfFilePrinter.AdobeReaderPath = @"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";

// Present a Printer settings dialog to the user so that they may select the printer
// to use.
PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();
settings.Collate = false;
PrintDialog printerDialog = new PrintDialog();
printerDialog.AllowSomePages = false;
printerDialog.ShowHelp = false;
printerDialog.PrinterSettings = settings;
printerDialog.AllowPrintToFile = true;
printerDialog.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
DialogResult result = printerDialog.ShowDialog();

if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
   // Print the document on the selected printer (We are ignoring all other print
   // options here
   PdfFilePrinter printer = new PdfFilePrinter("HelloWorld.pdf", settings.PrinterName);

   try
   {
      printer.Print();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
   }
}
```

**2)** Есть еще бесплатный [iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/), как печатать через него написано [тут](http://nilthakkar.blogspot.ru/2013/09/itextsharpprint-pdf.html).

**3)** Можно через [Spire.PDF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spire.PDF/), в бесплатной версии ограничение 10 стр.

```
using (var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument())
{
    pdfDoc.LoadFromFile(pdfFilePath);
    pdfDoc.PrinterName = "Printer Name";
    pdfDoc.PrintDocument.Print();
}
```

**4)** А вот [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/112707/) много чего по работе с PDF в C#.

Comment: А разве у iTextSharp не AGPL? Имею ввиду, что он вроде как не такой уж и "бесплатный".

Comment: @XelaNimed да согласен не такой уж и "бесплатный", но под словом "бесплатный" я имел виду, что за него не надо выкладывать деньги.

Comment: Я могу быть неправ, но насколько я понимаю, лицензия AGPL разрешает использование продукта, при наличии возможности получить исходный код программы. Другими словами: если исходный код конечного продукта будет доступен всем желающим, то можно пользоваться бесплатно, а если код будет закрыт, то необходимо покупать лицензию.

Answer (score 0):

Можно распечатать любой файл(ы) на любом принтере через командную строку LibreOffice. При этом окно приложения можно скрыть запустив его с ключем *headless*

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.exe" --headless --pt "Canon MF4010 Series UFRII LT" TestLabel.pdf
```

[Описание параметров командной строки LibreOffice](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Starting_the_Software_With_Parameters)

Работает гораздо стабильнее Adobe Reader, который запускается через раз.

Чтобы каждый раз не подставлять полный путь к файлу используйте:

```
private static string GetOfficePath()
    {
        const string keyBase = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths";
        const string fileName = "soffice.exe";

        var localMachine = Registry.LocalMachine;
        using (var fileKey = localMachine.OpenSubKey(string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", keyBase, fileName)))
        {
            if (fileKey != null)
            {
                return fileKey.GetValue(string.Empty).ToString();
            }
        }
        throw new Exception(string.Format("no installation of {0} found", fileName));
    }
```