# C# печать файлов xlsx без установленного MS Office

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, print

Есть шаблоны в xlsx файле, из которых я программно генерирую отчеты. Эти отчеты необходимо отправить на печать, но на машине не установлен MS Office.
Есть множество бесплатных библиотек для работы с таблицами, например ClosedXML или OpenXML, но только платные и далеко не все поддерживают печать выбранного листа на указанный принтер. Подскажите, как вывести документ Excel xlsx на печать из WPF на машине, где не установлен MS Office?! Использовать Excel Interop не предлагать! Желательно с примерами кода.

**UPDATE**

Остановился на том, что Excel файл сначала конвертируется в PDF, а затем печатается через командную строку LibreOffice.
Пример для PDF https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/707771/221115
Если отправить на печать Excel файл, в котором есть более одного листа, то LibreOffice напечатает первый лист. При конвертации в PDF вся книга объединяется.

Comment: Никак если судить по обсуждениям на форуме Microsoft (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9120bcd2-1266-4f14-9e23-a8b658adca20/how-can-i-print-excel-without-microsoftinterop-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: Есть способ, но дорогой Aspose.Cells for .NET Но как 1C формирует на печать файлы? Они в похожем формате как мне кажется

Comment: Тут какая ситуация получается - какая-то программа должна 
разобрать xlsx-файл и сформировать печатный макет, который можно будет передать принтеру. Если это не отдать на откуп MS Excel, то вам придется самому написать разбор и формирование объекта вручную. Для парсинга xlsl есть открытые библиотеки, а вот формирование макета придется создавать.

Comment: Подскажите как в таком случае сделать формирование отчетов не используя Excel формы и используя VS Community 2017?

Comment: @pwb, html-шаблоны как вариант

Comment: Попробую сконвертировать готовый Excel файл в pdf, а там уже надеюсь проще. Если получится успешный результат выложу здесь рабочий код.

Comment: Самый простой способ, который есть на данный момент это конвертация в pdf  с использованием LibreOffice. Через командную строку делается так: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.exe" --headless --convert-to pdf:"impress_pdf_Export" TestLabel.xlsx Создается pdf файл рядом с исходным файлом. Все делается в фоне и очень быстро.

Comment: Если не важно форматирование - то можно xlsx импортировать в с# а дальше делать с ним что угодно. В pdf переделать сложно, а в html будет не сложно, или в кастомный вид что можно печатать.

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите как в таком случае сделать формирование отчетов не используя Excel формы и используя VS Community 2017?

Вообще, для этого можно использовать RDL-отчеты. 
Посмотрите, к примеру на вот это - https://rdlcprinter.codeplex.com
Ну и погуглите на тему RDL viewer wpf.

Comment: Для моей задачи клиент хочет создавать шаблоны в удобной ему форме. Самое простое это было создание форм в Excel и последующая генерация отчетов на основе этой формы.

Comment: @pwb,так всегда. На вашем месте я бы показал бы клиенту RDL-дизайнер и вместе с ним бы оценил, а как часто он будет сам делать отчетные формы.

Comment: @pwb, можно предложить и другой тип шаблона документа, но тут всегда будет вопрос в удобном для него редакторе.

Comment: дело в том, что править шаблоны будут люди весьма далекие от RDL дизайнера - обычные работники, которые знают Word и Excel.