# Как распечатать pdf файл с помощью C#?

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-4.8

У меня есть корневая директория, в которой есть множество подпапок и в этих папках файлы pdf. Задача следующая: нужно рекурсивно обойти всё это файловое хранилище и поочерёдна печатать файлы на принтере, без открытия всяких диалоговых окон, то есть полностью автоматизировать этот процесс, чтобы пользователь указал только путь к корневой директории и нажал кнопку "Печать". С рекурсивным обходом я разобрался, но как выносить pdf файлы на печать? Я перепробовал кучу библиотек, такие как iTextSharp, PdfSharp, RawPrint, Spire.pdf, PdfViewer, но все они либо не выполняют требуемого функционала, либо, на примере Spire.Pdf печатают на листе бумаги, помимо содержимого pdf, дополнительную строку, типа эта версия только для ознакомления (то есть для реализации требуемого функционала нужно заплатить). Так же пытался решить задачу с помощью ссылки Acrobat Reader, но не получилось. Ещё всё усложняется тем, что версия .NET Framework у меня 4.7 (другую поставить не могу). Если есть кто-то, кто выполнял аналогичную задачу или знает хорошие библиотеки для печати pdf, буду рад вашим советам и примерам кода. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Я бы склеил все пдф в один большой тем же PdfSharp (у него есть метод AddPage), а потом его уже послал на печать

Comment: [Похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5566186/3129992), [ещё несколько способов](https://josipmisko.com/posts/c-sharp-print-pdf), [ответ на ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/707771/182750)...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распечатать PDF файл?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/571668/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-pdf-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb)

Comment: Я делал через  PdfSharp, файлик распечатывался, но проблема в том, что сверху, на листе бумаги, помимо содержимого дополнительно распечатывалась строка: "Evaluation Warning: The version can be used only for evaluation purpose..." Естественно это не годится, так как на листе должен быть только текст pdf. Поэтому я и прошу подсказать какие-то другие способы, бесплатные библиотеки или способ, как убрать эту строку.

Comment: Убрать легко - денег разработчику заплатить например